# Reading body from POST request

Tags: java, http

My task is to write a simple HTTP client and server, where the latter sends some JSON object to the server. I have decided to use [unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html), which is unfortunately poorly documented, but fairly easy to use.
The whole thing works almost as expected, except for one thing - server doesn't read body from POST method, only headers. Sending messages of a different size causes `content-length` to change its value, hence the client side is fine. The server's http response is also fine.

How can I fix this?

Server:

```
  public class SimpleHTTPServer {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
        System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 8080 ....");
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (!line.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
            clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(httpResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            clientSocket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
class Client {
    void send(String address, String message) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        String time = dtf.format(localDate);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject()
                .put("time", time)
                .put("address", address)
                .put("message", message);
        try {
            HttpResponse<String> postResponse = Unirest.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080")
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .header("Content-type", "application/json")
                    .body(jsonObject)
                    .asString();
            System.out.println(postResponse.getStatus() + " " + postResponse.getStatusText());
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE, "Couldn't connect to server!", ButtonType.OK);
            alert.showAndWait();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output (on server's side):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip
Content-type: application/json
user-agent: unirest-java/1.3.11
Content-Length: 66
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line is wrong, on the server side:

```
while (!line.isEmpty()) {
```

The documentation for `BufferedReader` says that it returns `null` at end of stream, not an empty string.